# Resource based (Imperative) authorization won't enter the handler

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, resource-based-authorization

Scenario:

- I have an API with .net core 2.2
- On top my controller I authorize access using IdentityServer4 with an Attribute
- Inside one of my endpoints I want to authorize access to a method only in some cases

I implemented [resource based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2) inside my endpoint just like it's shown in microsoft documentation.
It didn't work.
I put a breakpoint inside my authorization handler and tried debugging, but when this handler should be called, it is not.
I mean that when the following line runs

```
var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService
            .AuthorizeAsync(User, Document, "EditPolicy");
```

the Handler should be called, but that never happens.

Did anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end the problem was due to the registration of the service in the startup.cs.
I was using TryAddScope, by changing to AddScope it worked fine.